# Can we make icc a synonym of intraclass-correlation?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

We have two tags for intraclass correlation: [intraclass-correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intraclass-correlation) (which indexed 40 threads), and [icc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icc) (which indexed 6). I have retagged 5 of the latter (1 was migrated and couldn't be edited), and changed the wiki to indicate that it is a duplicate.  However, I cannot suggest that it is a synonym because I don't have 5 upvotes on [intraclass-correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intraclass-correlation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two tags have been merged, and [icc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icc) is now a synonym for [intraclass-correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intraclass-correlation).

Comment: Thanks for your help.